# Why is latex typesetting my fractions with so much vertical space?

Tags: fractions, vertical-spacing

I am using the normal `\frac` in display mode (`\begin{equation}`). This happens whether I'm using align, or double $, or whatever else.

This looks weird, right? Especially the numerator being so far away from the line.

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> This looks weird, right?

No, it looks *just fine*.

*Why*-type questions are frequently nearly impossible to answer. However, for the case at hand, it's rather straightforward to provide an excellent reason for why TeX's default settings for placing the numerator and denominator of `\frac` are actually just fine. For instance, consider the output of

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\tfrac' and '\text' macros
%% Just for demonstration purposes; please don't do this at home:
\newcommand\ttfrac[2]{\tfrac{\textstyle #1}{\textstyle #2}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon} \frac{ky}{lz} \quad\text{vs.}\quad
\ttfrac{\sigma}{\epsilon} \frac{ky}{lz}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

In my view, the only typographically reasonable way to typeset the double fraction expression is to place `\sigma` on the same baseline as `ky` and to place `\epsilon` on the same baseline as `lz`, as is shown on the left in the screenshot above. Conversely, it would be a typographical disaster to move `\sigma` down a bit and/or to raise `\epsilon` a bit, as is shown on the right.

If you examine the output of `\frac{ky}{lz}` closely, you'll notice that TeX places the numerator term `ky` such that there's just a bit of "breathing space" between the lower edge of the letter `y` and the fraction line. Ditto for the fraction line and the upper edge of the letter `l` in the denominator.

Finally, if you simply cannot stand the "look" produced by `\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon}`, I'd like to suggest that you employ inline-style fraction notation instead:

```
\begin{equation}
E = \sigma / \epsilon \,.
\end{equation}
```

[image]

This should be all the more acceptable as you have `$k=F/x$` right on the next line.

Comment: +1 for "_don't do this at home_" `:-)` One typo: "_to raise `\sigma` a bit_" should be "_to raise `\epsilon` a bit_".

Comment: +1. I believe that good examples are `\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}` and `\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}`

Comment: @campa - Thanks! Fixed the typo.

Comment: I had a feeling that I was the problem. Ok, thanks for this answer